vscode python not running: "/bin/sh: python: command not found"
i have a program in python, which wont compile in vscode
using python3 in terminal works, but in vscode it does not. here is the output it produced:
[Running] python -u "/Users/path/hello.py"
/bin/sh: python: command not found

[Done] exited with code=127 in 0.039 seconds

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling both python and vscode, but the problem still continues.  (im on mac)

Your python path is not correct. You can correct it by following this guide https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments. Also, I highly recommend using venv

@YoshikageKira i just put /path/ because my paths are... well... 'not safe for work' and im not sure if so likes that.

@YoshikageKira It looks like OP is using Code Runner, which doesn't respect the VSCode Python environment. It has its own config.

@ship_ /path/ is actually irrelevant the problem. The error is happening well before your program would even get read, much less compiled. The error says the shell can't find the interpreter, i.e. the command python.
